# Joomla web service module

Tags: service, joomla, module

I am looking for a Joomla web service module to allow users to create a user login and add posts and comments.

I am writing a standalone mobile version of my joomla site and I need it to call these web service functions.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla has an XML-RPC interface. However, it will be removed in Joomla1.6 btw.

Also take a look at:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/

And :
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/blog/3831